# How to load the method with variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the variables base from the user input and use that variable as the method name.

I have something like

function test(){
        this.control = $('.btn');
        this.init()
    }

```
test.prototype.init = function(){
    this.control.on('click', function(){
        var go = $(this).attr('id');  //go will have different direction  (up, down, right and left)
        this.go() //it gives me no go method error of course 
    })
}
  test.prototype.up = function(){

}
  test.prototype.down = function(){

}
  test.prototype.scrollRight = function(){

}
  test.prototype.scrollLeft = function(){

}


 var obj = new test();
```

How do I call different methods base on the element id in my case? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
this[go]()
```

so

```
this.control.on('click', function () {
    var go = this.id; //go will have different direction  (up, down, right and left)
    this[go]() //it gives me no go method error of course 
})
```